# Calculate real matrix inverse of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

Given a Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$.

If $B=A^{-1},\ D=\text{Re}(B),\ C=D^{-1}$.

where $D=\text{Re}(B)\Leftrightarrow{}d_{ij}=\text{Re}(b_{ij})$.

Can I calculate matrix $C$ from $A$ directly without calculating matrix inverse twice (or any methods that require lower operations than this)?

Comment: Just to clarify: by $real(B)$, are you referring to $\frac 12(B + B^*)$? Or, are you taking the real part of the entries of $B$?

Comment: Yes! $real(B)$ means the new matrix is form by real part of all the corresponding elements.

Comment: Note that $B^*$, for me, does not refer to taking the conjugate-transpose rather than the conjugate of the entries. So I would refer to the matrix that you are apparently discussing as $\frac 12 (B + \bar B)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\operatorname{Re}(B) = \frac 12 (B + \bar B)$. Note that $\bar B = \overline{A^{-1}} = \bar A^{-1}$, so that
$$
A(B + \bar B) \bar A = AB\bar A + A\bar B\bar A = \bar A + A = 2\operatorname{Re}(A).
$$
That is, we have
$$
2A \operatorname{Re}(B) \bar A = 2\operatorname{Re}(A) \implies \\
\operatorname{Re}(B) = A^{-1}\operatorname{Re}(A)\bar A^{-1} \implies \\
\operatorname{Re}(B)^{-1} = \bar A \operatorname{Re}(A)^{-1} A.
$$